# Why is my Java Tortoise and Hare Race not displaying properly?

Tags: java

I have seen several questions about the Tortoise and Hare Race but they are all pertaining to applets and I am not programming an applet. The program is meant to  I am having some trouble with the display output of my program. I would like to have the program display an output that looks something like this:

```
______T__________H________________________________
__________T_______________________H_______________
_____________T________H___________________________
```

etc. until either the tortoise or the hare reaches the end and wins the race. As of right now, my output looks like this:

```
______________________________HT__________________________________________________HT__________________________________________________HT_
```

over and over in what seems to be an infinite loop. Here is my code:

```
public class TortoiseAndHair {
public static void main ( String [] args )
{
    int t = 0; // Keeps track of tortoise progress
    int h = 0; // Keeps track of hare progress

    System.out.println( "AND THEY'RE OFF!!" );

    while (t < 50 || h < 50)
    {
        hareMove( h );
        tortoiseMove( t );



        if (t>1 && h> 1 && t == h) // Display when tortoise and hare occupy same space beyond start
        {
            System.out.print( "OUCH!!");
        }

        if ( t < 1 )
        { // Prevents tortoise from slipping behind start
            t = 1;
        }
        if ( h < 1 )
        { // Prevents hare from slipping behind start
            h = 1;
        }

        if ( t > 50 )
        { // Prevents tortoise from going passed finish line
            t = 50;
        }
        if ( h > 50 )
        { // Prevents hare from going passed finish line
            h = 50;
        }

        for ( int count = 1; count <= 50; count++)
        {
            System.out.print( "_" );
            if ( count == h )
            {
                System.out.print( "H" );
            }
            if ( count == t )
                {
                    System.out.print( "T" );
                }
        }

        if (h < 50 && t == 50)
        { //Output if tortoise wins
            System.out.print( "TORTOISE WINS!!" );
        }
        if ( t < 50 && h == 50)
        { // Output if hare wins
            System.out.print( "HARE WINS!!" );
        }
        if ( h == 50 && t == 50)
        {
            System.out.print( "IT'S A TIE!!" );
        }

    }

}

/**
 * This method will calculate the random integer that will dictate the tortoise's movements on the board,
 * use that random integer to determine the tortoise's movements (tMove), and add that to the counter keeping track
 * of the tortoise's position
 * @param t is an int variable that is keeping track of the tortoises position on the board
 * @return the tortoise's current position on the board after that turn
 * Pre-Conditions: n is an int between 1 and 10, t is a positive int greater than 0 and less than 50
 */

public static int tortoiseMove (int t)
{
    int n;
    int tMove = 0;

    n = (int) ( 10 * Math.random() ) + 1; // Generates random number between 1 and 10

    if ( n > 10 )
    { // ensures n doesn't go higher than 10
        n = 10;
    }

    // Series of if/else statements to control tMove
    if ( n >= 1 && n <= 5)
    { // Fast plod if n is between 1 and 5
        tMove = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( n >= 6 && n <= 8)
        { // Slow Plod if n is between 6 and 8
            tMove = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( n == 9 || n == 10 )
            { // Slip if n is 9 or 10
                tMove = -6;
            }
        }
    }
    // Add determined movement to tortoise counter and return that value
    t += tMove;
    return t;
}

/**
 * This method will calculate the random integer that will dictate the hare's movements on the board,
 * use that random integer to determine the hare's movements (hMove), and add that to the counter keeping track
 * of the hare's position on the board
 * @param h is an int variable keeping track of the hare's current position on the board
 * @return the hare's position on the board after current turn
 * Pre-Condition: n is an int between 1 and 10, h is a positive int greater than 0 and less than 50
 */

public static int hareMove (int h)
{
    int n;
    int hMove = 0;

    n = (int) ( 10 * Math.random() ) + 1; // Generates random number between 1 and 10

    if ( n > 10 )
    { // ensures n doesn't go higher than 10
        n = 10;
    }

    //Series of if/else statements to control hMove
    if ( n == 1 || n == 2 )
    { // Big hop if n is 1 or 2
        hMove = 9;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( n >= 3 && n <= 5)
        { // Small hop is n is between 3 and 5
            hMove = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( n == 6 )
            { // Big slip is n is 6
                hMove = -12;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( n == 7 || n == 8 )
                { // Small slip if n is 7 or 8
                    hMove = -2;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( n == 9 || n == 10 )
                    { // Hare falls asleep if n is 9 or 10
                        hMove = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Add determined movement to hare counter and return value of h
    h += hMove;
    return h;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You never reassign h and t after moving

```
 h = hareMove( h );
 t = tortoiseMove( t );
```

Primitives are passed by value, so whatever change you made to h and t in the move method are not reflected in the original values.

Comment: This, along with some other changes I made, worked. Thank you!